# How can I describe the methodology for this paper?

Tags: methodology

I'm writing a paper on philosophy about the role of spirituality in our lives. I'm using talks and debates between Jordan Peterson and Sam Harris and other debates available on Youtube. How can I describe the methodology for this paper?

Comment: Peterson and Harris? I hope you realize that these two do not constitute anything like a broad, unbiased overview of this topic; it's more like using a debate between Kim and Khloé Kardashian as the basis for a philosophical discussion of aesthetics.

Comment: While an outline of the argument is standard, I have yet to encounter an undergraduate essay with a methodology section in philosophy. Just describe what you do and why you do it...and since Ted is correct, try to find some critical papers to have a proper philosophical perspective as a base of discussion.